# Error in Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool after upgrading storyboard from xcode 4 to 5

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode5

After upgrading my MainStoryboard.storyboard to xcode 5, from Xcode 4, my project no longer compiles, it just stalls. And I can see in the Activity Monitor that Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool hawks all cpu and memory power, and force quitting this process is the only way to get xcode to stop compiling further.

Here's a rather lengthy console log file that was logged when Xcode stalled at compiling:
http://pastebin.com/c9q1yGuy

Answer (score 0):

Check row 14 in your log and try to find that view in your storyboard. Check its outlets and layout constraints to see if they are correct. Recompile and see if that row in the log disappears.

I guess this is due to `UITableViewCell` and its `UITableViewCellContentView` structure changes in iOS7. Just a guess thou.